# iOS7 Calendar Invitation using iCloud

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios7, icloud

I have seen [Sunrise Calendar App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sunrise-calendar-for-google/id599114150?mt=8) **which has feature to send invitation using iCloud** and I have searched lots of on google but I could not find any solution or any link to solve this issue.

Please suggest me any link or idea.

Thanks in advance for help